# Cosine similarity between sentences using Google news corpus word2vec model python

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, word2vec, cosine-similarity, sentence-similarity

I am trying to find **cosine similarity** between **two sentences** of unequal length using word2vec google news corpus but i am getting the error: `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1`

Below is my code:

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
EMBEDDING_FILE = '/root/input/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz' # from above
word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(EMBEDDING_FILE, binary=True)

vocab = word2vec.vocab.keys()
wordsInVocab = len(vocab)

import numpy as np

def sent_vectorizer(sent, model):
    sent_vec = np.zeros(50)
    numw = 0
    for w in sent:
        try:
            vc=model[w]
            vc=vc[0:50]

            sent_vec = np.add(sent_vec, vc) 
            numw+=1
        except:
            pass
    return sent_vec / np.sqrt(sent_vec.dot(sent_vec))

a = sent_vectorizer('Football is played in Brazil',word2vec)
b =sent_vectorizer('Cricket is played in India',word2vec)

word2vec.cosine_similarities(b,a)
```

I am converting the sentences into vectors as cosine_similarity takes vector array as input.
How do i resolve this?

Comment: You should show a full error stack of any errors you hit, so that answerers can see exact line(s) , in your code & the libraries used, involved with that error. But also: (1) is there a reason you're using 50-dimensional vectors, when the source word-vectors are 300-dimensional? (2) since your sentences are strings, your `for w in sent:` loop will make `w` each character in turn, not each word, which is probably not what your want; (3) division of the vec by the sqrt of its dot-product with itself is an odd & roundabout way to simply unit-normalize the vector (divide it by its own magnitude).

Answer (score 0):

`word2vec.cosine_similarities` takes in a vector as first argument and a `matrix` as second argument.

You are passing `vector` for second argument. Add one more axis or use `np.stack` to stack `a` and `b` together.